# How to use ggplot to group and show top X categories?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use use ggplot to plot production data by company and use the color of the point to designate year.  The follwoing chart shows a example based on sample data:
[image]

However, often times my real data has 50-60 different comapnies wich makes the Company names on the Y axis to be tiglhtly grouped and not very asteticly pleaseing.

What is th easiest way to show data for only the top 5 companies information (ranked by 2011 quanties) and then show the rest aggregated and shown as "Other"?

Below is some sample data and the code I have used to create the sample chart:

```
# create some sample data
c=c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH","III","JJJ")

q=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y=c(2010)
df1=data.frame(Company=c, Quantity=q, Year=y)

q=c(3,4,7,8,5,14,7,13,2,1)
y=c(2011)
df2=data.frame(Company=c, Quantity=q, Year=y)

df=rbind(df1, df2)

# create plot
p=ggplot(data=df,aes(Quantity,Company))+
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(Year)),size=4)
p
```

I started down the path of a brute force approach but thought there is probably a simple and elegent way to do this that I should learn.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this:

```
    df2011 <- subset (df, Year == 2011)
    companies <- df2011$Company [order (df2011$Quantity, decreasing = TRUE)]
    ggplot (data = subset (df, Company %in% companies [1 : 5]), 
            aes (Quantity, Company)) +
            geom_point (aes (color = factor (Year)), size = 4)
```

BTW: in order for the code to be called elegant, spend a few more spaces, they aren't that expensive...

Comment: Nice, but I was hoping to not just drop the small companies and instead aggreagate them and show them as "Other".

Comment: Sorry, I did overlook that part of the question. But anyways, it is not clear to me how exactly you want to aggregate them? Boxplot? Plot all points but in one row? Average? Median?

Comment: basically, just create a new company name called "Other" that aggregates the companies not in the "top 5".  so along the x axis there will be a total of 6 "companies" consisting of the "top 5" companies listed individually and "other" which is the sum of all non "top 5" companies.  im thinking basically just do something like.... df2=subset(df, Company %!in% companies [1:5])

Comment: well, use `!Company %in% companies [1:5]` instead, and `aggregate (df2, by = list (df2$Year), sum)`

Comment: great..thank you very much.  one last question, how can reorder the company names along the X axis such that they are sorted by descending order based on Quantity?

Comment: Mike, they appear in the order the levels of the Company factor have. I believe it's a ggplot2 FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

See if this is what you want. It takes your `df` dataframe, and some of the ideas already suggested by @cbeleites.  The steps are:

1.Select 2011 data and order the companies from highest to lowest on Quantity.

2.Split `df` into two bits: `dftop` which contians the data for the top 5; and `dfother`, which contains the aggregated data for the other companies (using `ddply()` from the plyr package).

3.Put the two dataframes together to give `dfnew`.

4.Set the order for which levels of Company are plotted: Top to bottom is highest to lowest, then "Other". The order is partly given by `companies`, plus "Other".

5.Plot as before.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# Step 1
df2011 <- subset (df, Year == 2011)
companies <- df2011$Company [order (df2011$Quantity, decreasing = TRUE)]

# Step 2
dftop = subset(df, Company %in% companies [1:5])
dftop$Company = droplevels(dftop$Company)

dfother = ddply(subset(df, !(Company %in% companies [1:5])), .(Year), summarise, Quantity = sum(Quantity))
dfother$Company = "Other"

# Step 3
dfnew = rbind(dftop, dfother)

# Step 4
dfnew$Company = factor(dfnew$Company, levels = c("Other", rev(as.character(companies)[1:5])))
levels(dfnew$Company)    # Check that the levels are in the correct order

# Step 5
p = ggplot (data = dfnew, aes (Quantity, Company)) +
        geom_point (aes (color = factor (Year)), size = 4)
p
```

The code produces:

[image]